# How can i fix this error with using captcha in django?

Tags: django, integer, captcha

My code (python version=3.10, django version=4.0):

```
def get_code(request):
    img = ImageCaptcha(200, 100)
    im = img.generate_image(chars='1234')
    fp = BytesIO()
    im.save(fp, 'png')
    return HttpResponse(fp.getvalue(), content_type='image/png')
```

Error:

```
TypeError at /get_code/
'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/get_code/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: You should post the rest of the exception. Also what is `ImageCaptcha`?

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
return HttpResponse(int(fp.getvalue()), content_type='image/png')
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```py
def get_code(request):
    img = ImageCaptcha(200, 100)
    im = img.generate_image(chars='1234')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    im.save(response, 'PNG')
    return response
```